# List of URLs and visits from Google Analytics API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to show number of visits of each article on my page. I am trying to download a list of urls and visits from Google Analytics using PHP class. I was searching for some sample code but no luck. I need result with all single urls and visits of these urls. I found only samples where people were getting total visits or visit of single url. I need a list of urls and visits.

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) might help?

Comment: which class do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [google-api-php-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client). It has a class "\Google_AnalyticsService" to perform analytics api calls. You can get your pagePaths by setting the "dimensions" of your query.